# How to create a txt file into the bin folder

Tags: java, filesystems

I am working on a java project and I was wondering if it is possible to write a code that can create a `txt` file directly into the `bin` folder (for example the bin folder for eclipse, where I can use `getClass()` to access the `txt` files) so that the user will not be able to see the created `txt` files when using the program.

Comment: What do you mean user will not be able to see it? He will always be able to do this as long as he has proper authorizations to access directories and files in the file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surely do this. But think again. User does not run program from Eclipse. User typically runs program packed in jar, so all class files are not in filesystem but into jar. Moreover the user even probably does not have rights to write into file system except special folders.

Bottom line: you you want to create application that stores some run-time data in file system you should either user user home or temporary directory or use `java.util.prefs.Preferences` that provide platform independent way to save and retrieve data using file system in unix and registry in windows.

If you choose to create file yourself you can retrieve use home and temporary directory using system properties `user.home` and `java.io.tmpdir`.

Comment: Can I create a temporary txt files within the generated jar at run-time or I have to use the java.io.tmpdir or any other directory?